# iosでOSのコマンドを実行することは可能なのでしょうか

Tags: ios

javaの場合、下記のような感じでOSのコマンドを実行可能なのですが、
iosから実行する方法はあるのでしょうか。
＃NSTaskで！と思ったのですがiosでは無理なようで…。

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = null;
try{
    proc = runtime.exec("ping -c 5 www.google.com");
    proc.waitFor();
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

できません。

- shellを含む多くのOSコマンドがiOSには搭載されていません
- 数少ない「OSコマンド」の存在するディレクトリにはアプリからアクセス出来ません
- 何らかの実行ファイルをアプリとは別のプロセスとして起動することもできません

Unix/Linux用のOSコマンドはほとんどオープンソースですから、使いたいコマンドのソースコードを入手して、ご自身のアプリの一部としてビルドし、その機能をアプリの一部として実行させる、と言うことでOSコマンドの実行内容と同じ処理をさせられるかも知れませんが、大変な手間がかかりますし、「OSのコマンドを実行」と言う言葉で語られているのとは全く異なるイメージなのではないかと思います。と言うわけで結論は最初に書いた通り「できません」です。

Comment: そうなのですね、知りませんでした。
デベロッパーのほうに、SimplePingなどがあり、
javaとかだと「runtime.exec」で実施してたので、わざわざライブラリ化されているのはなんでだろうと思った次第でした。
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html